# Amazon SES 'User not authorized to sendRawEmail' Only when a configuration-set is specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm currently trying to add open tracking to the emails that I'm sending through Amazon SES via a Laravel application.

When sending emails for a (full verified) domain, they send with no problem at all.

However, when I add a configuration-set to track opens/clicks, the email fails to send with the following error:

```
User `arn:aws:iam::<resource>:user/<user-name>' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:<region>:<resource>:configuration-set/<configuration-set-name>
```

The user in question has all ses permissions for all resources.

```
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:*",
            "Resource": "*"
```

Many thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70853850 similar.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using an extra policy with config-set to your role.

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ses:SendEmail",
        "ses:SendRawEmail",
        "ses:SendTemplatedEmail"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ses:region:xxxx:configuration-set/<configuration-set-name>"
      ]
}
```